# Change the value of select options based on the id attribute of the parent select element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple select options. If I select a specific `select` element, for example `id="a"` I want set the `option` values to `0`.

```
$('#form option:selected').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if(id == 'a') {
        val = 0;
    } else {
        val = 10;
    }
    console.log(val);
});
```

I got `undefined` value.

Comment: `$('#form option:selected').val(function() { return this.id==='a' ? 0 : 10 });`

Comment: do your `option` elements have an `id` attribute? https://jsfiddle.net/L8akrvsL/1/

Comment: @VictorLevin I want to get what is the ID name on `<select id='a'>` or `<select id='b'>`

Comment: You can use `$(this).parent().attr('id')` to get the parent `select` of the `option`. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L8akrvsL/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the reason your jQuery wasn't working was because `val` is an `undefined` variable. You should have been using `this.value` in order to set/get the value of the `option` element.

Based on your comments, if the `id` is on the `select` element, it appears as though you want:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/sy33rcmu/)

```
$('form option:selected').each(function() {
    var id = $(this).parent().prop('id');
    this.value = id === 'a' ? 0 : 10;
});
```

---

It's worth mentioning that you can simplify your code by just using the `.val()` method. It will iterate over the elements, all you need to do is return a value:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/z9qzopbk/)

```
$('form option:selected').val(function () {
    return $(this).parent().prop('id') === 'a' ? 0 : 10;
});
```

Comment: Thank you bro. Sorry for unclear question. Exactly what I need.